# Accessing list in xml

Tags: c#, xml

XML Data structure:

```
<CPT xmlns="http://www.example.org/genericClientProfile" xmlns:ns2="http://www.bosch-si.com/finance/cts/cpt/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/genericClientProfile genericClientProfile.xsd">
<header>
    <serviceId>CPT-UK</serviceId>
    <versionId>1.0</versionId>
    <brandCode>RBS.ADA</brandCode>
    <creationTime>2013-09-24T16:56:52.985+02:00</creationTime>
</header>
<clientProfile bpKey="19933" id="1bb26568-1df3-4206-8cea-fb4614bf0a6a" createdBy="BARBOURT" lastModifiedBy="MANNC" documentStructureVersion="V3_2" lastModifiedAt="2013-09-23 15:40:49.873" createdAt="2013-09-23 10:07:33.608">
<section xmlns="" id="cd21fbb5-da1b-485d-8909-a8392fd5ad5c" name="globalClientFacts">
    <attribute name="familyAndDependentComment" type="string">Tomas is 18 in 2013</attribute>
<list name="familyAndDependents">
    <entry entryId="1">
        <attribute name="famDependAge" type="decimal">0</attribute>
        <attribute name="famDependBirthdate" type="date" />
        <attribute name="famDependFinDep" type="boolean">false</attribute>
        <attribute name="famDependFinDepUntil" type="string" />
        <attribute name="famDependName" type="string">Tomas</attribute>
        <attribute name="famDependNat" type="xmlCountry">GB</attribute>
        <attribute name="famDependRel" type="enumeration">SON</attribute>
        <attribute name="famDependRelTo" type="string" />
    </entry>
<entry entryId="2"></list>
<attribute name="subCommentWills" type="string" />
</section>
```

I have the following data structure, What i'm looking to do is create SQL insert statements from each "section" which i have managed to do. However If a section contains a list, i need to get the list name and then the attributes for only one of the entries. Currently it seems to double the attributes as there are two entries.

C#:

```
    public void findAllNodes(XDocument doc, XNamespace ns)
    {
        StringBuilder attribute = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
        values.Append("(");
        var db = cptsqlentity();

        foreach (var f in doc.Descendants(ns + "clientProfile").First().Elements())
        {
            if (f.Attribute("name") != null)
            {
                values.Append(")");
                attribute.Append(")");
                attribute.Append(values);
                values.Clear();
                attribute.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                attribute.Append("INSERT INTO ");
                values.Append(" VALUES (");

                    OracleCommand oracleq = new OracleCommand("SELECT TABLE_SHORT FROM LOOKUP WHERE TABLE_LONG = " + "'" + f.Attribute("name").Value + "'" + " AND ROWNUM <=1", db);
                    OracleDataReader dr = oracleq.ExecuteReader();
                    dr.Read();
                    attribute.Append(dr.GetString(0));
                    attribute.Append(" (");
            }

            foreach (var p in f.Descendants())
            {
                if (p.Attribute("name") != null) {
                    attribute.Append(p.Attribute("name").Value + ",");
                    values.Append("'" + p.Value + "'" + ",");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you have `.Select(e => e)`? And can you give more details as to what the actual results are with the sample data you've given? It's not clear.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Also, the code you've given wouldn't even compile, which means it's clearly not the code which is "doubling the attributes". It's hard to help you without seeing some code which *really* reproduces the problem. If you could produce a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, that would be ideal.

Comment: Updated with actual method used.

Comment: @MarcHoward I'm still fairly certain you're not giving us actual working code. For example - you're iterating through all descendants of `clientProfile`, looking for a specific attribute - `name`. At least one such descendant - `<entry entryId="1">` does not have that attribute, so the following line `attribute.Append(p.Attribute("name").Value + ",");` would fail with a `NullReferenceException` (unless I misremember how `XElement.Attribute` works)

Comment: Sorry just realised, I forgot to include the if statement, checking for the name attribute.. otherwise yes it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about the schema for your XML file, but wouldn't the following do?

Replace your last `foreach` statement with the following:

```
foreach (var p in f.Elements("attribute")
                   .Union(f.Elements("list")
                           .SelectMany(l => l.Elements()
                                             .First()
                                             .Elements("attribute"))))
{
   //...
}
```

This gives you all `attribute` children of the `section` element together with all `attribute` children of the first child of all `list` elements (which are a child of your `section`).

Does that make sense?

Comment: What if i wanted to return just the list attributes from the first entry?

Comment: `f.Elements("list").SelectMany(l => l.Elements().First().Elements("attribute")))`